# Как сохранить passphrase для gpg?

Tags: linux, gpg

Настроил автоматическую сборку rpm-пакетов из исходников с помощью jenkins.
Остаётся настроить их подпись, НО при запуске rpm --addsign file.rpm gpg спрашивает Passphrase для ключа (но только один раз). Как его сохранить, чтобы при ребуте сервера не надо было заново его вводить?

P.S. gpg-agent --allow-preset-passphrase ничего не даёт

через expect пароль не вводится

Comment: https://aaronhawley.livejournal.com/10615.html

Comment: И правильно делает. Иначе создавайте ключ с пустой парольной фразой.